# Detect on what side the home button is when device is face up

Tags: ios, swift, device-orientation

As a part of an application that I am currently working on I am required to click an image and then show the resultant image in the correct orientation.

Keeping in mind that the user can click the image in any available orientations (portrait, landscape left/right, face up). I am able to achieve the desired result for all modes, but faceup orientation.

My question is: **Is there a way of detecting on which side my home button would be when the device is face up? If so, how can I achieve the same?** Please note that the application is meant to be a portrait only application. So using status bar orientation is pretty much out of the window I guess.

Looking forward to hear your thoughts on the same.

Comment: Those going through this. I couldnt figure out a way to do the same. This made me move onto plan b which was to show a rotate button.

Comment: Do you found answer to this question? I can only detect landscape/portrait in this situation when UIDeviceOrientation returns faceUp/unknown by taking ratio of UIScreen.main.bounds

Comment: Na man.. This was for a project in my old company. I've moved on since but as far as I remember the problem has still persisted

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
if UIDevice.current.orientation == .portraitUpsideDown {
     print ("Divice oriented vertically, home button on top")
}
```

There are also `faceDown`, `faceUp`, and others. 
Check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uideviceorientation?language=objc) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Getting the home button location is easier for portrait, portrait upside down, landscape left and landscape right. However this method will not respond be of no help when the orientation is face up.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your needs, you should use `UIInterfaceOrientation` instead of `UIDeviceOrientation`, although they are somewhat similar, they have different effects.

When your device orientation is face up/down, your UI orientation is still one of the top, bottom, left, and right.

Sample code.

```
switch UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation {
    case .portrait:
      print("Home button in bottom")
    case .portraitUpsideDown
      print("Home button in top")
    case .landscapeLeft
      print("Home button in left")
    case .landscapeRight
      print("Home button in right")
    default:
      print("The interface may be rotating.")
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this something that is totally out of my hand as it is a requirement from the client. This could be a possible solution if supporting both portrait and landscape orientations, albeit with a lot of work required to support the views on both orientation. But currently not a solution to the problem I am facing.

Comment: @iOSer No problem. We can keep this answer for those who need it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeRight {

        ...

    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft {

        ...

    } else if UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portrait {

        ...

    }
    else {

         ...
    }
```

Comment: Have you thought of using a `switch`?